# How to run a long function in a thread to prevent GUI freezing?

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter

I am fairly new to programming and am making a program that searches through information about rugby players in a file (about 123,300 players) and displays the players that match the users search criteria with `tkinter` in Python 3.

I have a search button that is binded to a `search()` method, which gets the users input, calls run_search to search the file for matches, and displays the matches to a canvas. It works fine except that the GUI freezes when the button is pressed, and only unfreezes a few seconds later when the search is finished and the matching players' info is drawn to the canvas. The actual searching function of the search() method is written in a different .py file, player_search_engine.

So far I understand that `tkinter` executes things serially, and so the GUI cannot be redrawn until the `run_search()` part is done. I looked around and the solution is to do the search in a different thread, or manually call `update()` on the GUI. The latter was advised against and wouldn't work for me anyway, and most solutions just say to "start another thread". I have no idea how to do this, and am not even sure what a thread is except that it might let the code run in parallel. I tried to copy a few examples that used classes for progress bars, but the GUI still froze the same.

Here is all the relevant (I think) code

```
import player_search_engine
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import threading

class scouting_tool(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.root = parent
        self.draw_search_panel()
        self.draw_results_panel()

    def draw_search_panel(self):
        ...

    def draw_results_panel(self):
        ...

    def draw_found_players(self):
        #displays a row showing the details of a player for every found player

    def search(self, event):
        #gets the input from all the search fields, applies them to the search engine settings,
        #and searches the database using them. Then displays all matching players

        #get the nationality from the combobox
        player_search_engine.target_nationality = self.nat_list.get()

        #get the inputs from the entry boxes
        player_search_engine.min_weight = self.get_entry_box_data(self.min_weight_box, 60)
        player_search_engine.max_weight = self.get_entry_box_data(self.max_weight_box, 160)
        ..etc 


        #run the search
        self.search_thread = searchThread()
        self.search_thread.start()
        self.search_done_check()


    def search_done_check(self): 
        if self.search_thread.done_event.is_set(): 
            self.draw_found_players() 
        else:
            super(scouting_tool, self).after(20, self.search_done_check)

class searchThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.done_event = threading.Event()

    def run(self):
        player_search_engine.search_database()  
        self.done_event.set()

app = scouting_tool(None)
app.title("BR Scout")
app.wm_resizable(False, False)
app.mainloop()
```

So, how do I create a working thread for the `search_database()` function so that the GUI will not freeze while the function runs?

Comment: Have you googled "python thread"? There's plenty of information on how to start a thread, what a thread is, how it can help you, etc. [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm) is an example.

Comment: See Python `multiprocessing` package https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html. There are a lot of tutorials, eg.: https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html

Comment: I tried making a thread subclass, it still freezes but now it works long enough for you to see the button get pressed down, before it froze with it still looking unpressed

Answer (score 0):

I guess your attempt with a thread didn't really work because `self.draw_found_players()` waits for the end of the thread execution to draw
the players (so in fact it is the same as not using a thread at all).

I recommend you to do the following:

- search your database in a thread, like you tried
- in your thread class, create a `threading.Event` object called `done_event`: `self.done_event = threading.Event()`
- in your main `search` method, start a Tkinter timer to repeatedly check
  if the thread is done, without blocking the GUI. Add a `search_done_check` method
  like this:

  def search_done_check(self):
      if search_thread.done_event.is_set():
          self.draw_found_players()
      else:
          self.root.after(100, self.search_done_check)

And after you start the thread, trigger the first `search_done` check:

```
self.search_done_check()
```

So at the end you combine a thread doing computation with a Tkinter timer to
check if it is done, and then you use the results.

Comment: Thanks, I did that and added `self.done_event.set()` to the end of the `run` method because it was never recognising that it had finished searching, but the behavior is still the same with freezing. I've updated the new code

Comment: Your updated example spawns a thread, tries to use the results immediately, spawns again, and then does the polling check. I'm guessing that code is either wrong, or you added the suggested behavior without removing the bad behavior.

Comment: my bad didn't update the code properly, its there now, but the behavior is still the same

Comment: so your problem is not in this particular piece of code because from here it looks ok

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the database is on the same machine, so there is no network lag.  To avoid threads, break data processing into chunks and use one of tk's own schedulers, specifically .after_idle. An outline of the code:

```
def start_process(args):  # command attached to button
    <open database, do other initialization
    root.after_idle(process_block, newargs)

def process_block(args):
  <do about 10 ms of work>
  root.after_idle(process_block, newargs)
```